# form with two submit buttons redirecting to two different urls

Tags: javascript, html

I have to create a html form with two submit buttons

both of them have to capture the data and then redirect to different pages

I used this code

```
<input type="button" name="submit1" value= "submit" onclick="first();">
 <input type="button" name="Submit2" value= "submit and refill "onclick="second();">
```

and in the head I defined the functions

`

```
**<script type="text/javascript">
function sub() {
new name.target = 'https://www.google.com';
new name.submit();
}
function subr() {
new name.target = 'https://www.gmail.com';
new name.submit();
}
</script>**
```

but it is not working.. I only have to use javascript and html

plzzz plzzz help!!

Comment: Your functions have the wrong names?

Comment: Where are the `first()` and `second()` functions?

Answer (score 1):

you have wrong names for functions.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function first() {
new name.target = 'https://www.google.com';
new name.submit();
}
function second() {
new name.target = 'https://www.gmail.com';
new name.submit();
}
</script>
```

Comment: oh I changed them here only .. in the code they are the same still they are not working

Comment: you need to specify the form names

Comment: new name is the form name only